# Postgres - Using regex with COPY when reading a table from CSV

Tags: regex, postgresql

I was trying to create a table from the IMDB database.
Problem is, that when using the copy command when reading from the CSV file, there are multiple values that I would like to set as NULL.

Using NULL AS doesn't seem to work with more than expression. I tried with this code to no avail:

```
CREATE TABLE title_basics
(
    tconst VARCHAR PRIMARY KEY,
    titleType TEXT,
    primaryTitle VARCHAR,
    originalTitle VARCHAR,
    isAdult INT,
    startYear SMALLINT,
    endYear SMALLINT,
    runtimeminutes SMALLINT,
    genres VARCHAR
);

COPY title_basics
FROM '-- path --'
DELIMITER ',' NULL AS '[a-zA-Z\]' CSV HEADER;
```

The values that I want to set to NULL are '\N', 'Reality-Tv' and 'Animation, Action, Fantasy'.
A big problem seems to be the '' because Postgres regex then reads it as an escaping character.
It tried passing multiple expressions like '[][]', however it didn't work either.
Anyone who can solve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Import data first, and do update after that

Comment: Hi Slava, thanks for the reply! Do you mean setting all of them to e.g. string or varchar and then transform their datatype and exclude the NAs?

Comment: I solved it by importing data first and then doing an update command for each condition not satisfied by the '\N', since seemingly UPDATE can only handle one argument at a time.